# QlikView messing up date conversion

Tags: qlikview

I've recently found out that one of my QlikView documents messes up date conversion where it didn't before.

If I choose a date from a calendar (for example if I choose 01/02/2017, format 'DD/MM/YYYY'), that date gets stored as 42767. At the point, if I try to change that number into a date using `Date($(vDate),'YYYYMMDD')` I get as a result 19000210 instead of 20170201 (tried with different dates and formats without better results).

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Have you tried experimenting with the Date# function? You can define how your date is formatted and then return the format you desire by using Date(Date#(DateField, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'YYYYMMDD')

Comment: How are you setting the value of vDate variable? I have observed that when the date string is not surrounded by quotes such problem appears. Example vDate='01/02/2017' gives proper value but vDate=01/02/2017 gives garbage.